# Laravel display the encrypted column on the database

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, eloquent

in my model I have this field `address` that is encrypted. I encrypt using the `casts`

```
protected $casts = ['address' => 'encrypted'];
```

I tried creating an accessor on the model

```
    public function getAddressAttribute($value)
    {
        try {
           $decryptedValue = Crypt::decryptString($value);
        } catch (\Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException $e) {
           $decryptedValue = ""; //or null
        }
        return $decryptedValue;
    }
```

but when I try to access it it will return as null/empty depending on what I put

```
            "email": "flangosh@example.com",
            "name": "Kim Schulist",
            "address": "",
```

Is there something wrong on my method?

Also when I remove the try catch statement or dont use accessor What I got is
`"message": "The MAC is invalid.",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting a parameter as `encrypted` automatically encrypts/decrypts the value, in both directions, as appropriate. You are effectively double-decrypting in your accessor, which fails.

(If you remove the try/catch stuff, you'll be getting the `DecryptException` of "The payload is invalid".)

*edit:* In this case, the try/catch masked errors caused by OP's changing the `APP_KEY` value. That value is used as the encryption/decryption secret; any changes to it will break any existing encrypted data in the database. (A data migration is possible, but, somewhat messy and requires the old `APP_KEY` value to perform.)

Comment: i see. but when I dont do it. i got an error `DecriptionException: The MAC is invalid`. any ideas?

Comment: also tried removing the try or not using the accessor catch i got ```"message": "The MAC is invalid.",```

Comment: Do you have older data that was never encrypted in this table? Or have you changed `APP_KEY` in the `.env` file? If so, you'll have to manually migrate it.

Comment: nope. but I changed the `APP_KEY` via `artisan key:generate` should I migrate the database again?

Comment: @draw134 Changing the APP_KEY will break any existing encrypted data. It is the encryption secret that is used to encrypt/decrypt information.

Comment: ohh okay seems I got it. maybe i need to migrate:fresh the database again and seed it. right?

Comment: Assuming you don't mind wiping the database, yes. (Sounds like this is local development?) If this is production data you'd have a messier set of things to do.

Comment: yes. this is still on local development. its okay now, i refreshed the database. i should put in mind that changing the APP_KEY is crucial :D . can you update your answer so I can mark it as correct? Thanks :)

Comment: @draw134 Edited the answer to cover both aspects.